# Change timezone inside MySQL insert request?

Tags: mysql, timezone

I am running my site shared hosting and their timezone is off, theres no way to change default timezone.

Can i set timezone inside MySQL query? 
e.g. `INSERT INTO mytable name=john age=20 time=NOW() WHERE id=11 and TIME ZONE = 'New York/NY'`

Answer (score 4):

You can put this after making the connection.

```
SET time_zone = "-5:00"
```

This will set the time zone for all the queries on the connection. You can also use known time zones, ie, "America/New York", but if it's unknown, you have to add this manually to a time zones table. Refer to [this blog post](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-set-timezone-per-connection/) to see how.